# Upper bound of the set

Tags: general-topology

I am struggling with understanding of the concept of the upper bound of the set:
in Rudin, it says: Suppose, $S$ is an ordered set and $E$ is a subset of $S$. If there exists $b \in S$ such that $x\le b$ for any $x \in E$, than $E$ is bounded above, and $b$ is an upper bound of $E$. But what about $S$ itself? What if $S=(0,1)$, so there is nothing else. My prof says that if the set is given, assume nothing else exists, but this set. Can we consider $S$ bounded in $S$ or not? There is no such $b \in S$ that for any $x \in S x\le b$. Or the concept of bound is defined for the proper subset only?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You appear to be new here.  I was a little surprised to see that your question wasn't immediately answered, but then I looked at your profile.  If you show a history of not properly selecting answers that helped you, people will be less likely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Boundedness (above or below) need not be defined for proper subsets only. Consider instead the real interval $(0,1],$ which is bounded above in itself, but not below.

Comment: So, it means that (0,1) is unbounded in itself? If yes, it means it is not compact?

Comment: True, $(0,1)$ is unbounded in itself, and if an ordered set is unbounded in itself, then it fails to be compact (in the order topology). However, "closed and bounded in itself" does not in general give us compactness. Consider the set $[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ This is closed in itself (since all topological spaces are), and readily bounded in itself, but it is not compact, since the cover by the open sets having form $$\left[0,1-\frac1{2^n}\right)\cup\left(2+\frac1{2^n},3\right]$$ (for integers $n\ge1$) cannot be reduced to a finite subcover.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much. I secretly hoped it would be that exciting, and it is!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no such $b \in S$ such that $x \leq b$ for all $x \in E$ then $E$ is unbounded from above.  In this definition, you always need to define a parent set, $S$.  That is the place of *potential* upper bounds.  In your example of $S = (0,1)$.  Then $S \subseteq S$ is an unbounded (from above) subset of $S$.  However, it is true that $(0,1) \subset (0,2)$ is bounded from above, by namely $b = 1$, or any other element larger than $1$ in $(0,2)$.

Does this clarify anything?

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understood correctly,then it means (0,1) is unbounded if it is a parent set. So, it is not compact on itself?